# create simple angular project using svgs

Tags: angular

create  simple angular project the ui can be anything.the goal is to you need to use svgs and images in ui.these assests should not be directly used like <img src/img.svg.you need to build an angular project that takes SVGS and coverts them into webfonts and we need to use webfonts in our html.build a simple ui with 5 imAGES used as an icon

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is an Angular problem. Can you explain what is html.build?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

to work with .svg I know differents ways

```
<img src="img.svg">
```

//or

```
<svg class="bi " width="1rem" height="1rem" fill="currentColor" >
     <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#menu-app" />
</svg>
```

//or

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
<path fill="currentColor" d="M3.5,0l-1,5.5c......></path>
</svg>
```

or using fortAwesome, you can in the app.module use some like

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

var faMyIcon = {
  prefix: "fas",
  iconName: "myIcon",
  icon: [
    15,
    15,
    [],
    "f0000",
    "M3.5,0l-1,5.5c-0.1464,0.805,1.7815,1.181,1.75,2L4,14c-0.0384,0.9993,1,1,1,1s1.0384-0.0007,1-1L5.75,7.5 c-0.0314-0.8176,1.7334-1.1808,1.75-2L6.5,0H6l0.25,4L5.5,4.5L5.25,0h-0.5L4.5,4.5L3.75,4L4,0H3.5z M12,0c-0.7364,0-1.9642,0.6549-2.4551,1.6367C9.1358,2.3731,9,4.0182,9,5v2.5c0,0.8182,1.0909,1,1.5,1L10,14c-0.0905,0.9959,1,1,1,1s1,0,1-1V0z"
  ]
};
....
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(faMyIcon);
  }
}
```

And use as

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'myIcon']"size="6x"></fa-icon>
```

I don't know if this help you or not