# how to display an svg image using angular-svg-icons package in typescript angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I am trying to add an svg image to a svg-icon in typescript but to no avail. This is how i am currently doing it.

```
let jtiImageElement = document.createElement('svg-icon');
    jtiImageElement.setAttribute('src', 'assets/icons/jtis/1A.svg');
    //jtiImageElement.setAttribute([stretch],"true");
    //jtiImageElement['src'] = `assets/icons/jtis/1A.svg`;
    jtiImageElement['[svgStyle]'] = "{width.px:'100', height.px:'100'}";
```

An svg-icon is displayed in the DOM with dimensions of 0x0. There is no image being shown however. Please help

Comment: don't use document.createElement, just put in your .html some like `<svg-icon name="eye" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':90 }"></svg-icon>`, see the docs: https://github.com/czeckd/angular-svg-icon#readme. BTW, Until now, the four ways to show a .svg I knowed are showed in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971784/create-simple-angular-project-using-svgs/62972704#62972704, sorry, I

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response, but is it not possible to use typescript to add the svgs? This is for a webapp where a map will be shown, and these svg images are boards  will be shown as an overlay(openlayers) on the web app. I would like to use svgs to manipulate them (such as flashing borders) and it is not possible to do so using img element.

Comment: it's possible if you use html elements, but if you use an angular component not. If you use angular components try re-think the app using *ngFor to create the necesaries `<svg-icons>`